# YouTube API retrieve demographic information about a video

Tags: python, youtube-api, gdata

Is there a way to pull traffic information from a particular youtube video (demographics for example, age of users, country, gender, etc.), say using the python gdata module or the youtube API? I have been looking around the module's documentation, but so far nothing.

Answer (score 0):

There used to be a large selection of things in the past, but they are all gone now. So do not think it is possible any more.